# Assign array values without specific index

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, variable-assignment

I'm a beginner who wants to try Java programming, I've got a problem when I want to add a value to arrays (that has been instantiated before) without inputting the specific index

```
public void readData() {
    books = new Book[10];

    while (true) {
        book = new Book();
        process = new BookProcess();
        System.out.printf("%nData Application%n");
        System.out.printf("%nApplication menu%n");
        System.out.printf("=============%n");
        System.out.printf("[S] Show Book%n[A] Add books%n[E] Edit book%n[D] Delete book%n[X] Exit%n");
        System.out.printf("%nChoose Menu [S/A/E/D/X]");
        inputData = scanner.nextLine();
        process.setMenu(inputData);

        while (true) {
            if (process.getMenu().equals("A") || process.getMenu().equals("a")) {
                if (true) {
                    System.out.printf("%n%-10s: ", "No. Book");
                    inputData = scanner.nextLine();
                    if (inputData.equals(""))
                        book.setNobook(inputData);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

after that I want to show the data in table like this

```
System.out.printf("%-25s", book.getNobook());
```

Because I'm a beginner, my knowledge about methods in Java is still limited, but how can I add the values `book.SetNobook(inputData)` to `book.getNobook()` without mentioning the specific index (random), so after looping I can add another value to the array as long as it doesn't exceed the number of indexes of the array. I want to know the basic method not the advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to use your array like a dynamic list. You need another variable to keep track of the last occupied (or first free) index, and increment it whenever you add a book. This is essentially what the class [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) does, internally.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're adding to anything. Maybe you can provide an example input that would cause confusion.. An array probably isn't the correct data type, but I bet you could use it. You could also use a List or a Set or any number of Collection.